# Usage: tmutil listlocalsnapshots <mount_point>

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, time-machine, disk-space

my Mac's system has 184GB. I believe that's for time machine's local snap shot.

[image]

I tried to tmutil list localsnapshots, but Usage: tmutil listlocalsnapshots <mount_point> returned.

I’m not clear what <mount_point> means for me.

Specifically,  how can I use tmutil listlocalsnapshots to list and then delete local snapshots in an effort to free space?

Answer (score 1):

The mount point of your system is /

The good command is

`tmutil listlocalsnapshots /`

Comment: when I use command tmutil listlocalsnapshots / , 
nothing happens..

Comment: So there is no snapshots on your system.

Comment: @AinBlurr What do you mean 'nothing'? At the very least it should respond with `Snapshots for disk /:` even if there are no snapshots.